# Why winforms textbox stole a focus

Tags: vb.net

I have very basic winforms application with two buttons 'btn_OK', 'btn_cancel' and 'Textbox1'.
Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True

    btn_cancel.TabIndex = 0
    btn_OK.TabIndex = 1
    TextBox1.TabIndex = 2
    TextBox1.TabStop = False
    TextBox1.Multiline = True

    TextBox1.Text = "Quick brown fox say's hello world."
    btn_cancel.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_cancel_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles btn_cancel.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        btn_OK.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_OK_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles btn_OK.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        btn_cancel.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Idea is to fill a textbox with text, set focus to btn_cancel and with pressing to keys.Left move focus to btn_OK.
But that don't happens.

By pressing left key focus jumps to textbox instead of btn_OK even if textbox's TabStop property is set to false!

This is very unexpected and unwanted.
What is happening here and how to get expected functionality?

Comment: The Tab and cursor keys are intercepted before they can reach the control with the focus.  Winforms uses them to take care of navigation automatically.  So your KeyDown event handlers never run and the TabIndex properties you've set are in control.  Override the ProcessCmdKey() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't necessary, stop trying that way and define your custom tab positions using the `TabOrder` Page from Visual Studio options menu.

> View > TabOrder

[image]

In the example, the first button focused is "0", if I press Right key it will focus "1", If I press Left then it will focus "0", and so.

Comment: That was not a question at all, so it is not answer too.